# How to unit test graphql query/mutation error with Mocha and Chai?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Since `graphql` error is not an standard `Error`. It's a `GraphQLError`

I can't figure out how to write unit test when `graphql` query/mutation throw an exception.

Here is my try:

```
it('should throw an error when lack of "id" argument for user query', async () => {
    const body = {
      query: `
        query user{
          user {
            id
            name
          }
        }
      `
    };

    try {
      const actualValue = await rp(body);
    } catch (err) {
      logger.error(err);
    }

    // logger.info(actualValue);
    expect(1).to.be.equal(1);
    // expect(actualValue).to.throw()
  });
```

I found some tests in `graphql.js` repo. [https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/**tests**/starWarsQuery-test.js#L393](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/__tests__/starWarsQuery-test.js#L393)

But I think the way they test the `query/mutation` error is not correct.

They just do a deep equal with the error. But before running the test suites, how do I know the error data structure like `locations: [{ line: 5, column: 13 }],`? Maybe I should use snapshot testing so that I don't need to know the error data structure?

Answer (score 0):

Check this package https://github.com/EasyGraphQL/easygraphql-tester there is an example with mocha and chai on the documentation